# When selecting a subset of a table, hibernate does not auto cast it into the business domain object in a list

Tags: sql, hibernate, select

When i am selecting a full table

> i.e. select * from product

, Hibernate returns me a list of Product objects. However, when i am selecting only a subset of it,

> i.e. select name, price from product

, Hibernate returns me a list of objects which it is unable to cast it into a list of Product objects out of the box. Any attempts to cast it into a list of Product objects causes ClassCastException.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<UserRoleAndProgramCategory> get(int roleId, int programCategoryId) {
    String sHql;
    String[] key;
    Object[] value;

    key = new String[] { "roleId", "programCategoryId" };
    value = new Integer[] { roleId, programCategoryId };

    sHql = "select distinct l.userId, l.userName, l.fullName, l.roleId, l.roleName, l.roleCode, l.programCategoryId, l.programCategoryCode, l.programCategoryDescription from "
            + UserRoleAndProgramCategory.class.getName()
            + " as l where roleName <> ' ' and roleCode not in ('CONTRACTOR', 'ADMIN') and programCategoryId = :programCategoryId and roleId = :roleId";

    return (List<UserRoleAndProgramCategory>) super.getQueryWithCache(sHql, key, value, false, false, false)
            .getQueryResult();
}
```

Thank you. Please let me know where i have went wrong.

Comment: I found this from Hibernate's forum which says
"You query and return say two properties of your class, and the result is a list of arrays of length two; now just think about what might be appropriately returned as elements of that array... Might seem to make sense that the first position might correspond to the first property requested and the second correspond to the second. Now, just what might be the types of those returns? Hrrrmmm? The java types for the corresponding property types maybe? Could it be that easy?"

[link] https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=935654&view=previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-select).

In order to return a list of objects from a query that selects specific properties, you need to use an Alias To Bean transformer.

[Example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e17601) (for SQL queries, but HQL works the same)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I will try that now.

Answer (score 1):

```
sHql = "select distinct new UserRoleAndProgramCategory(l.userId, l.userName, l.fullName, l.roleId, l.roleName, l.roleCode, l.programCategoryId, l.programCategoryCode, l.programCategoryDescription) from "
            + UserRoleAndProgramCategory.class.getName()
            + " as l where roleName <> ' ' and roleCode not in ('CONTRACTOR', 'ADMIN') and programCategoryId = :programCategoryId and roleId = :roleId";
```